# Excel VBA - Formula Breaks After Adding Data in Spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with monthly costs for Jan. 2016 through Dec. 2016 (columns M through X). There are also two buttons on the sheet.  When you click the "Perform Analysis" button, it reduces each monthly cost by the percentage entered in column D (i.e. if you enter 15 in column D, columns M (January) through X (December) are reduced by 15%).

Once columns M through X are reduced, then columns Z (Jan. 2017) through AK (Dec. 2017) are populated.  To determine the value of columns Z through AK, I see if the average monthly cost for 2016 is greater than or less than the difference between the original total yearly cost for 2016 (column Y) and the newly reduced cost.  If the average cost is greater than the difference, then Jan. 2017 (column Z) is equal to the difference between the original cost and reduced cost.  If the average is less than the difference, then Jan. 2017 is equal to the average monthly cost for 2016.

Next, we use the same logic as above to determine the value of column AA (Feb. 2017).  However, this time we are subtracting the value of Jan. 2017 from the difference between the original yearly cost for 2016 and the newly reduced cost.

For example, if the original yearly cost for 2016 was $350,000 and the reduced cost was $297,500 (reduced by 15%), and the average monthly cost was $45,000 (also the cost for Jan. 2017), then we would calculate the value for Feb. 2017 by saying:

If average monthly cost ($45,000) greater than ($350,000 - $297,500 - $45,000) Then Feb. 2017 = $275,300

Else average monthly cost ($45,000) less than ($350,000 - $297,500 - $45,000) Then Feb. 2017 = $45,000

This pattern continues through Dec. 2017, column AK.

All of my code was working great, until I added numbers to Row 5 in my spreadsheet.  After I added the data, my COUNTIFS formula no longer returns the correct result.

For Row 5, `MonthsWithValues` should equal 10; however, each time I run the code now, it gives me a 0.  I have tried debugging it using Step Into, Break Points/Toggle Points, and Watch.  Each time I run the code, it keeps saying the value of `MonthsWithValues` is 0. Because my code contains a formula where you divide by `MonthsWithValues`, I keep getting Run-time Error 11 (you can't divide by 0).  Help!
The relevant code is:

```
Function ReduceCost_Percentage()

With Worksheets("Analysis Worksheet")

Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim Orig2016Total(65) As Long
Dim MonthsWithValues As Long
Dim TodayDate As Date
TodayDate = Format(Date, "DD/MM/YYYY")

For i = 5 To LastRow
Orig2016Total(i) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(("BC" & i), ("BN" & i)))
MonthsWithValues = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range(("M" & i), ("X" & i)), "<>0", "<>")
Next i

For i = 5 To LastRow
If .Range("D" & i).Value > 0 And IsEmpty(.Range("B" & i).Value) And IsEmpty(.Range("C" & i).Value) Then
  If .Range("X" & i).Value > 0 And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) _
  And Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value <= #12/31/2016# Then
    If (((Orig2016Total(i) - (Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value * (12 - Left(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value, 2)))) / MonthsWithValues)) < (Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value) Then
      .Range("Z" & i).Value = ((Orig2016Total(i) - (Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value * (12 - Left(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value, 2)))) / MonthsWithValues) + Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value
    End If
  ElseIf .Range("X" & i).Value > 0 And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) _
  And Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value <= #12/31/2016# Then
    If (((Orig2016Total(i) - (Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value * (12 - Left(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value, 2)))) / MonthsWithValues)) > (Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value) Then
      .Range("Z" & i).Value = (Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value) + Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value
    End If
  ElseIf .Range("X" & i).Value > 0 And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) And Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value > #12/31/2016# _
  And (Orig2016Total(i) / MonthsWithValues) < (Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value) Then
    .Range("Z" & i).Value = Orig2016Total(i) / MonthsWithValues
  ElseIf .Range("X" & i).Value > 0 And IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) _
  And (Orig2016Total(i) / MonthsWithValues) < (Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value) Then
    .Range("Z" & i).Value = Orig2016Total(i) / MonthsWithValues
  ElseIf .Range("X" & i).Value > 0 And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) And Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value > #12/31/2016# _
  And (Orig2016Total(i) / MonthsWithValues) > (Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value) Then
    .Range("Z" & i).Value = Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value
  ElseIf .Range("X" & i).Value > 0 And IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) _
  And (Orig2016Total(i) / MonthsWithValues) > (Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value) Then
    .Range("Z" & i).Value = Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value
  ElseIf .Range("X" & i).Value = Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) _
  And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value) And Orig2016Total(i) > 0 Then
    If (((Orig2016Total(i) - (Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value * (12 - Left(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value, 2)))) / MonthsWithValues)) < (Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value) Then
      .Range("Z" & i).Value = ((Orig2016Total(i) - (Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value * (12 - Left(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value, 2)))) / MonthsWithValues) + Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value
    End If
  ElseIf .Range("X" & i).Value = Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) _
  And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value) And Orig2016Total(i) > 0 Then
    If (((Orig2016Total(i) - (Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value * (12 - Left(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value, 2)))) / MonthsWithValues)) > (Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value) Then
      .Range("Z" & i).Value = (Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value) + Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value
    End If
  ElseIf (IsEmpty(.Range("X" & i).Value) Or .Range("X" & i).Value = 0) And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) _
  And Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value > #11/30/2016# And Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value <= #12/31/2016# Then
    If ((Orig2016Total(i) - (Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value * (12 - Left(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value, 2)))) / MonthsWithValues) < (Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value) Then
     .Range("Z" & i).Value = ((Orig2016Total(i) - (Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value * (12 - Left(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value, 2)))) / MonthsWithValues) + Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value
    End If
  ElseIf (IsEmpty(.Range("X" & i).Value) Or .Range("X" & i).Value = 0) And Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) _
  And Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value > #11/30/2016# And Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value <= #12/31/2016# Then
    If ((Orig2016Total(i) - (Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value * (12 - Left(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value, 2)))) / MonthsWithValues) > (Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value) Then
     .Range("Z" & i).Value = (Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value) + Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value
    End If
  ElseIf (IsEmpty(.Range("X" & i).Value) Or .Range("X" & i).Value = 0) And ((Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) And Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value > #12/31/2016#) Or IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value)) _
  And (Orig2016Total(i) / MonthsWithValues) > (Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value) Then
    .Range("Z" & i).Value = Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value
  ElseIf (IsEmpty(.Range("X" & i).Value) Or .Range("X" & i).Value = 0) And ((Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value) And Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("C" & i).Value > #12/31/2016#) Or IsEmpty(Worksheets("Fixed Cost Test Data").Range("B" & i).Value)) _
  And (Orig2016Total(i) / MonthsWithValues) < (Orig2016Total(i) - .Range("Y" & i).Value) Then
    .Range("Z" & i).Value = Orig2016Total(i) / MonthsWithValues
  End If
End If
Next i
```

Comment: I think you want to add them `MonthsWithValues = MonthsWithValues + Excel...`

Comment: The last part of your formula should be `"<>"""""` (or just `"<>"`) instead of `"<>"""` (unless you are trying to check for the existence of a quotation mark within the range), but that isn't the reason for your problem.

Comment: What are you using for the With block that your code is within?  If it is a worksheet, is it the one with your data on it?

Comment: There is insufficient data to reproduce your error. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I have re-formatted my question above and added the relevant code.  Please let me know if I need to add or clarify anything.

Comment: @HeatherD The third argument of your `COUNTIFS` is a criteria; it should be a range. And there should be a 4th argument as a criteria. And why do you repeat the `COUNTIFS` multiple times?  You seem to only be using the final result.

Comment: @HeatherD  In general, a VBA Function is used to return a value; a VBA Sub is used to modify the worksheet.  Sometimes mixing that will work, sometimes it may have unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks @RonRosenfeld!  I had been playing around with the formula for `MonthsWithValues`, and someone else suggested I take out my range as the third argument; good to know I had the formula formatted correctly originally.  And thanks for explaining the difference between using a sub and function - will definitely keep that in mind going forward.

Answer (score 1):

It was giving me the error because `MonthsWithValues` wasn't being initialized with a number, so it was being evaluated to 0.

The correct code is:

```
Sub ReduceCost_Percentage()

With Worksheets("Analysis Worksheet")

Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim Orig2016Total(68) As Long
Dim MonthsWithValues(68) As Long

For i = 5 To LastRow
Orig2016Total(i) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(("BC" & i), ("BN" & i)))
MonthsWithValues(i) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range(("M" & i), ("X" & i)), "<>0", .Range(("M" & i), ("X" & i)), "<>""""")
Next i
```

Now it works! Thanks for the help everyone!